PowerAutomate - Add row to Excel table - Multiple branches for different people - Failing when in new look PowerAutomate
I have created a flow that takes information from a completed Form and adds rows to tables in multiple excel documents stored in SharePoint folders. There is a different document for each employee (15 in total). When I created the flow, it worked with no issues, but since the new look PowerAutomate has been active, the flow keeps failing.
I try to switch to old style and whilst I can fix the issue there, after about 15 minutes it fails again when testing. Any ideas?  Is this a glitch with the new look PA?

Can you please share the error message and snapshot of your flow please?
